# Role based authorization in ASP.Core 3: how to grant access everywhere to certain role?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, abac

I am writing a ABAC system in which I will decide if a user can access to certain data based on some roles/atributes/etc. However, there is a special kind of user (something like superadministrator) who should be able to access everything, everywhere, always. I don't want to go through all policies, controllers, actions and methods and add a check on this specific role. Is there a way to do it in a more centralized way? (for example: in the `startup`).

If it is not possible to add it to a global place, I was thinking on adding it at least globally on a controller level: I was looking [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and I saw that the decorator `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` lets you restrict the access to a certain method/class just to Administrator users. However, I want kind of "the opposite". I mean something like an `AuthorizeAlways` that had the following behaviour:

```
[AuthorizeAlways(Roles = "SuperAdministrator")]
public class ControlPanelController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "SetterUser")]
    public ActionResult SetTime()
    {
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "PowerUser")]
    [MinimumAgeAuthorize(50)]
    public ActionResult ShutDown()
    {
    }
}
```

In this case I'd like that `SuperAdministrator` (even if they are 49 years old) has access to everywhere. A `SetterUser` has access only to `SetTime` and only a `PowerUser` who is older than 50 years old can access `ShutDown`.

I don't know if this makes much sense. Is it possible? Where could I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blog post provides a good tutorial for how to implement custom authorization:
https://seanspaniel.wordpress.com/2019/12/13/custom-authorization-in-asp-net-core-3/

From that tutorial, in the CustomAuthorizationMiddleware class you could check for the "SuperAdministrator" role and grant access to every endpoint.

```
public static class CustomAuthorizationMiddleware
{
    public static async Task Authorize(HttpContext httpContext, Func next)
    {
        var endpointMetaData = httpContext.GetEndpoint().Metadata;

        bool hasCustomAuthorizeAttribute = endpointMetaData.Any(x => x is CustomAuthorizeAttribute);

        if (!hasCustomAuthorizeAttribute)
        {
            await next.Invoke();
            return;
        }

        CustomAuthorizeAttribute customAuthorizeAttribute = endpointMetaData
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x is CustomAuthorizeAttribute) as CustomAuthorizeAttribute;

        // Check if user has allowed role or super administrator role
        bool isAuthorized = customAuthorizeAttribute.AllowedUserRoles
            .Any(allowedRole => httpContext.User.IsInRole(allowedRole)) 
             || httpContext.User.IsInRole("SuperAdministrator");

        if (isAuthorized)
        {
            await next.Invoke();
            return;
        }

        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("unauthorized");
    }
}
```

Comment: when registering the middleware, make sure to add it AFTER authentication - so the user is authenticated and their information is added to the HttpContext BEFORE endpoint authorization. Otherwise httpContext.User will not have the user's information and you will always get an unauthorized response.

Comment: Yes, I have `userRouting`, then `useCors`, `useAuthentication`and then `useAuthorization`. I don't understand why your tutorial does not use `useAuthorization`, though...

Comment: the UseAuthorization extension method is the built in middleware offered by Microsoft - if you want to implement your own authorization logic you have to replace it with custom middleware. That's what the tutorial is for. If you are unfamiliar with middleware and the request pipeline you can read the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1